# Is PyRun_SimpleString() function slow?

Tags: c++, optimization, python-c-api

I have C++ app where it does many calculations, but the most of time it needs to execute simple scripts by `PyRun_SimpleString()` so I'm curious if is there something in Python/C API, what would do faster following tasks:

1. do simple assignents like `x = 0.1` (changing over time)?
2. execute script storaged in string (maybe something like compile once to run faster)?

For now I do all these tasks by executing `PyRun_SimpleString()`. In loop performance loss is significatn.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, there's indeed two parts to running Python code: interpretation and execution. See `Py_CompileString` and `PyEval_EvalCode`. But for simple statements like `x=0.1`, you might even consider modifying locals yourself via `PyLong_FromDouble(0.1)`